# How to get Document number in sales transaction window in Microsoft Dynamic GP 2010

Tags: econnect

This Question is duplicate. May be i have n't clearly wrote the question before..

See below Question..

Let me know is it possible to get Document number and Invoice number which is selected from Sales Transaction Window in Microsoft Dynamic GP 2010.

I have one requirement.
I have to create one menu option in sales transaction window.Using that option i have to print the information which is selected(Currently) Document number and Invoice Number in sales Transaction window.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at a Dynamics GP customization using Visual Studio Tools for Dynamics GP or Visual Basic for applications in Dynamics GP. Using either of these technologies you can access the currently selected document number in the Sales Transaction Entry window and take action on it.